# Passing JS variable value to PHP variable to update database

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

If you want to see the part where I tried AJAX, go look down below. It completely messed up the page and I'm stuck on how to do this. I've got some code here:

```
$id = $_SESSION["id"];
$sql = "SELECT riskcoin FROM klanten WHERE id='$id'";
$INFO=mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
if (mysqli_num_rows($INFO) > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($INFO)) {
        echo "riskcoin: " . $row["riskcoin"].  "<br>";
        $riskcoins = $row["riskcoin"];
    }
} else {
   echo "0 results";
}
?>

var dealerHand = [];
var playerHand = [];
var currentHand;
var deck;
var deckCount;
var countCards = true;
var bets = new Bets();


// Bets Object
function Bets() {
   this.pot = <?php echo "$riskcoins"; ?>;
   this.bet = 0;
   $('#bet').text(0);
   $('#pot').text('$' + this.pot);
 }

// Bets methods
Bets.prototype.updateAmounts = function () {
   $('#bet').text('$' + this.bet);
   $('#pot').text('$' + this.pot);
};
Bets.prototype.doubleDown = function() {
   this.pot -= this.bet;
   this.bet += this.bet;
};
Bets.prototype.potAmount = function() {
    return this.pot;
};
Bets.prototype.betAmount = function(){
    return this.bet;
};
Bets.prototype.disableDeal = function () {
    $('#button-deal').addClass('disabled');
};
Bets.prototype.addBet = function(amount) {
    if (this.pot >= amount) {
        this.pot = this.pot - amount;
        this.bet = this.bet + amount;
        this.updateAmounts();
        $('#button-deal').removeClass('disabled');
    } else {
        notEnoughChips();
    }
};
```

First part is php second part js. I have an int value in my database called riskcoin. `this.pot` contains that riskcoin value (//Bets object) and shows itin another php file in a paragraph with `id="pot"`.

When an image is clicked another function ads an amount to the bet depending on the picture (for example 5).

Now my question: after the line  `this.updateAmounts();` it executes

```
// Bets methods
Bets.prototype.updateAmounts = function () {
   $('#bet').text('$' + this.bet);
   $('#pot').text('$' + this.pot);
```

Now my question would be if I could update the riskcoin value in my database with an update query after this function with the current this.pot value? It should show live updates without page refreshes. I've read about AJAX so I tried something like this:

```
Bets.prototype.updateAmounts = function () {
    $('#bet').text('$' + this.bet);
    $('#pot').text('$' + this.pot);
    window.history.pushState('page2', 'Title', '?coins=' + this.pot);
    $(document).ready(function(){
    var url = window.location.href;
    var params = url.split('?coins=');
    var id = (params[1]);
        $("#button-deal").click(function(){ $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url:"blackjackgame.php",
        data:{id:id},
        success:function(result){
        $("#pot").html(result);
        }
        });
        });
    });
};
```

But it for some reason when I click on the deal button (#button-deal) it shows up my login page in the middle of the page under all the other stuff, console gives me:  `GET http://riskybusiness.nglyceum.eu/games/login.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)jquery-3.1.1.js:5921`

Comment: Your PHP ought to be in a separate file than the Javascript. That file produces something like `0 results\n\nvar dealerHand = [];`. Also, your `updateAmounts()` adds the event listener to the button. Do you need to wait until `addBet()`, and then `updateAmounts()` are executed THEN add the event listener to the button?

Comment: When/why is `#button-deal` clicked? How/when is `addBet()` executed?

Comment: Can you post your blackjackgame.php?

Comment: @bloodyKnuckles someone selects how many coins he wants by clicking on a few images (#bet/this.bet) ->addBet() checks if he has enough coins if yes game gets started if #button-deal is clicked and the button then gets greyed out/disabled. Then updateAmounts() gets executed. If he hasn't got enough coins then a sweetalert is given notEnoughChips()

'   this.pot = <?php echo "$riskcoins"; ?>;
'
is the amount of coins

Comment: @6opko all of the code I've posted here is in blackjackgame.php 
Do you want me to post the complete page?

Comment: @AA you're making an ajax POST to blackjackgame.php from blackjackgame.php?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP and Javascript execute in different contexts. PHP on the server, Javascript on the client (browser). Keep your PHP code and Javascript separate. Since PHP executes first on the server, you can embed PHP output into your HTML/Javascript/CSS—BEFORE—it is sent to the browser.

One problem you have with your code is intermingling PHP and Javascript, such as:

```
<?php
if (mysqli_num_rows($INFO) > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($INFO)) {
        echo "riskcoin: " . $row["riskcoin"].  "<br>";
        $riskcoins = $row["riskcoin"];
    }
} else {
   echo "0 results";
}
?>

var dealerHand = [];
var playerHand = [];
var currentHand;

// Bets Object
function Bets() {
   this.pot = <?php echo "$riskcoins"; ?>;
   this.bet = 0;
   $('#bet').text(0);
   $('#pot').text('$' + this.pot);
 }
```

The PHP (only) gets processed on the server, and this text is sent to the client:

```
riskcoin: 100<br>

var dealerHand = [];
var playerHand = [];
var currentHand;

// Bets Object
function Bets() {
   this.pot = 100;
   this.bet = 0;
   $('#bet').text(0);
   $('#pot').text('$' + this.pot);
 }
```

Also, this `$("#button-deal").click(function(){` in your code adds a click event handler to your button. The problem is, you're not adding this event handler until `addBet()` is executed, which then executes `updateAmount()`. Not only don't wait, but the handler is added each time `addBet()` is executed. Instead add the event handler on page load.

---

I've separated the various code components into server-side execution and client-side execution contexts, and properly connected them to each other:

```js
var dealerHand = [];
var playerHand = [];
var currentHand;
var deck;
var deckCount;
var countCards = true;
var bets = new Bets();

// Bets Object
function Bets() {
  this.pot = 100; // <?=$riskcoin?>;
  this.bet = 0;
  $('#bet span').text('$' + 0);
  $('#pot span').text('$' + this.pot);
  $('#deal button').addClass('disabled');
}

// Bets methods
Bets.prototype.updateAmounts = function() {
  $('#bet span').text('$' + this.bet);
  $('#pot span').text('$' + this.pot);
};
Bets.prototype.potAmount = function() {
    return this.pot;
};
Bets.prototype.betAmount = function(){
    return this.bet;
};
Bets.prototype.addBet = function(amount) {
  if (this.pot >= amount) {
    this.pot = this.pot - amount;
    this.bet = this.bet + amount;
    this.updateAmounts();
    $('#deal button').removeClass('disabled');
  } else {
    notEnoughChips();
  }
};

// add the click event handler on page load
document.querySelector("#deal button").addEventListener("click", evt => {
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "deal.php", // <-- post data to separate PHP file, see PHP file below
    data: {bet: bets.betAmount()},
    success: function(result) {
      const win = (result > bets.pot)? " (won)": " (lost)";
      bets.pot = result;
      bets.bet = 0;
      $("#pot span").text('$' + bets.pot + win);
      $('#bet span').text('$' + bets.bet);
      $('#deal button').addClass('disabled');
    }
  });
});

document.querySelectorAll("#bet button").forEach(btn => {
  btn.addEventListener("click", evt => {
    bets.addBet(parseInt(evt.target.textContent));
  });
});

function notEnoughChips() {
  alert("Not enough chips.");
}

// mock ajax, remove in real world
$.ajax = (function () {
  return function (params) {
    if (Math.random() < 0.5) {
      params.success(bets.pot + (params.data.bet * 2));
    } else {
      params.success(bets.pot);
    }
  };
}());
```

```css
.disabled {
  cursor: not-allowed;
  pointer-events: none;
  color: #c0c0c0;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<!-- uncomment in the real world
<?php

$id = $_SESSION["id"];
$sql = "SELECT riskcoin FROM klanten WHERE id=?"; // <-- use prepared statements
$INFO=mysqli_prepare($conn, $sql);
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "i", $id);
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
if (mysqli_num_rows($INFO) > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($INFO)) {
        $riskcoin = $row["riskcoin"];
    }
} else {
   $riskcoin = 0;
}

?>
-->

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="pot">Pot: <span><?=$riskcoin?></span></div>
<div id="bet">Bet: <span>0</span> <button>+5</button><button>+10</button><button>+15</button><button>+20</button></div>
<div id="deal"><button>Deal</button></div>
```

deal.php (The JQuery ajax function POSTs to this file.)

```
<?php

// this file called in JQuery ajax function found in "#deal button" "click" handler

$id = $_SESSION["id"];
$bet = $_POST["bet"];

$sql = "SELECT riskcoin FROM klanten WHERE id= ?";
$INFO=mysqli_prepare($conn, $sql);
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "i", $id);
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
if (mysqli_num_rows($INFO) > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($INFO)) {
        $riskcoin = $row["riskcoin"];
    }
} else {
   $riskcoin = 0;
}

// random win or lose
$riskcoin += ((bool)random_int(0, 1))? ($bet * 2): (-1 * abs($bet));

$sql = "UPDATE klanten SET riskcoin = ? WHERE id = ?";
$INFO=mysqli_prepare($conn, $sql);
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ii", $riskcoin, $id);
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

echo $riskcoin;

?>
```

Comment: `<div id="pot">Pot: <span><?=$riskcoin?></span></div>` in a html file?

Comment: Good point. You *can* (I do) but the server needs to be configured to run ".php" and ".html" files through the PHP processor. I updated my answer to not confuse people.

Comment: Thanks. Had to change a few things so it would work with the other code I had but it finally works now!

Answer (score 1):

```
// Bets Object
function Bets() {
   this.pot = <?php echo "$riskcoins"; ?>;
   this.bet = 0;
   $('#bet').text(0);
   $('#pot').text('$' + this.pot);
 }
```

You cannot put php code inside of javascript as PHP is server side so it runs before javascript.

I believe your best option would be to use php for all of it.

Comment: She/he can as I'm guessing that's their intent is to render PHP code before the javascript in order to get  this.pot = <?php echo "$riskcoins"; ?>; defined (e.g.  this.pot = 5;), based on the MySQL query at the top of the page